# I need help figuring out a cleanable backsplash for this oven alcove

Tags: kitchens, cleaning, oven, backsplash

I am doing upgrades to the kitchen in a home that I rent out. I would like to make this area easier for my future tenant to keep clean. I have already removed the shelf and brackets. I am familiar with custom stainless steel backsplashes, but if there isn't a ledge at the base of the backsplash, doesn't that mean anything could just drip onto the floor behind the stove? Any help would be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: You're worried about stuff falling behind the stove between the wall and the high control panel?

Comment: I imagine in that space the stove is the best idea, but seems odd to me.  I would imagine a pantry or fridge there and the stove more in the open with countertops.

Answer (score 1):

Install the cabinets and countertop around the stove that are now just resulting in a lot of wasted space, (were I "future tenant", I'd consider that a defect and look for a better rental) and if you want stainless (a good, easily cleanable and durable backsplash for this application) provide it with a bent out gutter along the bottom (or run it into pre-formed U channel attached to the wall first, which may cost less for similar effect) and the "drip" concern is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I used laminate, the same used for countertops in my last home. It was still good and easy to clean 20 years later when we sold it. I used contact cement. If you do not vent the area when installing the glue will make you "happy" so pick the glue carefully.